# What are some obstacles/issues you face while working in industry?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, automotive-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, construction-management

As part of a project incubator program at my university, I am trying to understand current specific issues, cumbersome processes, and obstacles facing engineering projects in industry. By pinpointing a specific issue, my team and I would be able to develop a potential solution to the problem.

For instance, I read about how this team of engineers designed a tray that can stick onto inclined surfaces (airplane nose, etc.) so that technicians can easily handle tools.

I consider myself a creative person and love to come up with solutions. However, I need to identify specific inefficiencies and issues in industry. As I do not have work experience, I am hoping that you can provide that insight. As many of you come from a wide range of industries and different positions, I would really value your input and opinion.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Didn't NASA spend 5 million designing a pen for astronauts that would write in space at all angles, low temperature etc? And the Russians just gave the astronauts a pencil??

Comment: This is too general. Start by finding a *specific* problem where you can identify a solution. Forget about the "In industry" part - there are lots of engineering products used by ordinary members of the public (and remember that includes people who may be very young, very old, have medical impairments, are right or left handed or footed, etc, etc...)

Comment: But I need help finding a specific problem. With this question, I'm trying to identify specific problems engineers face at their work. I'm trying to create a product that can benefit engineers in their industry.

Comment: SE sites are for asking specific questions and getting specific answers. See [Don't ask](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for details. You would be better asking this on a discussion forum.

Comment: @ARJ why wouldn't the engineers solve their own problems?

Comment: ok here's one. After I don't even know how many years, printing still sucks. You walk into a new office you need to be at for the day, they have a beautiful million DPI, 200 pages per minute,  color, double sided, scanning, faxing, auto stapling, will make you an origami if you want, but it's still a 30 step process to hook up on wifi to print a simple page. Go fix that.